# What is the point of using `MISSING` in hydra or pydantic?

Tags: python, config, pydantic, hydra

I am creating a configuration management system in python and are exploring options between hydra/pydantic/both. I get a little confused over when to use `MISSING` versus just leaving it blank/optional. I will use an example of [OmegaConf](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/2.1_branch/structured_config.html#nesting-structured-configs) here since
the underlying structure of hydra uses it.

```
@dataclass
class User:
    # A simple user class with two missing fields
    name: str = MISSING
    height: Height = MISSING
```

where it says that this `MISSING` field will convert to yaml's `???` equivalent. Can I just leave it blank?

Comment: What I don't quite get is why the example they give, `another_num: int = MISSING` doesn't cause a mypy type checking error, since `MISSING` is actually defined as `"???"` in `omegaconf.py`. Looking forward to someone answering your question.

Comment: From the docs `Omitting a default value is equivalent to assigning MISSING to it, although it is sometimes convenient to be able to assign MISSING it to a field.`

https://hydra.cc/docs/1.1/tutorials/structured_config/config_groups/#missing-fields

Comment: @NikolayManolov Yeap saw that as well, I am still unsure how this `MISSING` makes it more convenient, is it somewhere down the pipeline that this becomes useful/apparent?

Comment: Hmm, I don't have a particular usecase in mind. But usually, you can't have fields without a default value after fields with default values (in the order of fields for a partiular dataclass), so assigning MISSING makes your field technically have a default value, which internally is handled as no-value. I guess it could also be somehow useful for code validation/anlysis, etc.